# Align a button the bottom center in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to align a button to the bottomcenter of the screen

I created a buttomappbar in a scaffold i want to include a round button but i don't want to use the default fab. Im using another round button and i tried to align the button to the buttomcenter using the Align widget but it stays in the center.

```dart
class _MainActivityState extends State<MainActivity> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        backgroundColor: HexColor("ECEDEF"),



        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.threed_rotation)
            ],
          ),
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: CircularGradientButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.gradient),
              callback: (){},
              gradient: Gradients.rainbowBlue,
              shadowColor: Gradients.rainbowBlue.colors.last.withOpacity(0.5),
            ),
          )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

I want the CircularGradientButton to come to the bottomcenter above the BottomAppBar

Comment: do you have a picture/sketch of what you're trying to achieve specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a stack you can achieve that. Set fit property to: `StackFit.expand` then use a positioned with `bottom:0` and `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Center(
              child: MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.threed_rotation)],
        ),
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
```